# cannot assign a value on a custom NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am probably missing or not seeing something very basic but I can't debug it anymore.

Here is my code :

```
NSLog(@"Joker Selected : %d, Prio Value is :%@",joker,[LBGameData sharedGameData].round.joker_1_used ? @"true" : @"false");
[LBGameData sharedGameData].round.joker_1_used = TRUE;
NSLog(@"End of selection, Prio Value is :%@",[LBGameData sharedGameData].round.joker_1_used ? @"true" : @"false");
```

Here is the definitions.

**LBGameData**

```
@property (strong, retain) LBGameRound* round;
+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
```

**LBGameRound**

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL joker_1_used;
```

This is my output :

```
2015-10-18 18:54:01.478 Game[804:298953] Joker Selected : 1, Prio Value is :false
2015-10-18 18:54:01.479 Game[804:298953] End of selection, Prio Value is :false
```

Why I can't see the `true` in the second output, although i set it on the line above?

Comment: Have you verified that `[LBGameData sharedGameData]` and `[LBGameData sharedGameData].round` are not `nil`? BTW - use `YES` and `NO` with `BOOL` values.

Comment: @rmaddy correct, round was nil. Make it an answer so I can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Added answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the output, the most likely issue is that either `[LBGameData sharedGameData]` or `[LBGameData sharedGameData].round` are `nil`.

Trying to access the `BOOL` value from the `nil` value will result in a `NO` value resulting in the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try by the following way.

```
  BOOL joker_1_used = [LBGameData sharedGameData].self.round.joker_1_used =TRUE;
  NSLog(@"End of selection, Prio Value is :%@",joker_1_used? @"true" : @"false");
```

**Output:**

```
 End of selection, Prio Value is :true
```

Comment: But the OP has a shared instance of `LBGameData`, not `LBGameRound`.